# Why can't I add my non-gmail Google account to iPhone?

Tags: ios, calendar, google

I tried to add my Google account to iPhone in order to see my calendar in the iOS Calendar app. However the Settings app just went back to the previous page, without any error message. What's going on?

If it's relevant, my Google account is not a gmail address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue for some non-gmail Google accounts. You can vote for the following issues:

- [Google community forum post #12918619](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/12918619/i-can-t-add-my-google-account-to-my-iphone-enter-my-google-email-and-password-but-just-grey-option)
- Apple community forum post https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7647157

Some workarounds:

1. Use the Google Calendar app
2. 'Add subscribed calendar' -- this will be readonly iCal https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648